# How to display local storage on html

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

im trying to display the output of local storage

```
function addSampleNotes() {

    localStorage. setItem( '2020-09-28 13:35:00', 'Call Tony about blog code');
    localStorage. setItem( '2020-10-02 07:00:00', 'Buy eggs');
    localStorage. setItem( '2020-10-14 16:21:00', 'Hang out the washing');
}

addSampleNotes();

for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
  console.log( localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) );
}
```

This manages to come up in the console perfectly however i want it to display on my html page

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");

for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
  output.innerHTML = ( localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) );
}
```

tried adding something like this but i get null errors.
How can i display my local storage on the html?

HTML

```
<body>
    
    <fieldset>
       <legend>My Tunings</legend>
       <div id="output"></div>
    </fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js">
    </script>
    
  </body>
```

error is

````
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at js.js:14```
````

Comment: You might need to include your HTML.

Comment: First thing: use `+=` for `output.innerHTML`, and add a `<br>`:
`output.innerHTML = (localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))+"<br>";`

Comment: And your `for` loop:
`for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)`.

Comment: You should provide your HTML and the errors that you're getting so we can actually help you.

Comment: Your `script` should go before the closing body tag

Comment: Im aware the script should go before the closing tag. I just put it at the top for testing reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you put every item into its own element. For example paragraphs, or in your case an unordered list `ul` would be best.

Like so:

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var element = document.createElement("p")
    element.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))
    output.appendChild(element)
}
```

Prefer `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` if you are not setting HTML, as it is a possible security threat.

The error you posted in your edit, tells you that `output` variable on which you are trying to operate is null. Make sure that you do not have a syntax error and that you run JavaScript after HTML is loaded.